# How to delete a remote branch using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, git

I'm currently using [nodegit](http://www.nodegit.org/) to run my git commands and it has worked for everything so far except for deleting a remote branch. I don't mind using another npm package to do this if needed but I would prefer to use nodegit.

Basically, I want a function which can do the same as this command in the terminal

```
$ git push -d <branch_name>
```

I want to be able to write something like the following:

```
function delete_remote_branch(repo, branch_name, callback) {
  repo.getRemote('origin').then(function(remote) {
    repo.getBranch(branch_name).then(function(reference) {
      // delete the branch
      repo.push("-d :"+reference, branch_name).then(function(error_code) { 
        if(error_code) {
          return callback(error_code)
        }
        return callback(null)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

The documentation for remote.push is here: http://www.nodegit.org/api/remote/#push

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Deleting references is done by pushing an empty local reference to it, like you can do with git's push command. So pushing [":refs/heads/branch_name"] would delete the branch on the remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push an empty src reference to the origin branch.

```
remote.push(':refs/heads/my-branch');
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try later and if it works then I'll mark this as correct :)

Comment: Yep, tested it out and it worked! Thank you so much!